# Calculate the area under each peak in a graph in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to calculate the area under each peak in a graph that I plotted with a set of x and y co-ordinates,

I don't have a function for (x,y), and so I haven't been able to find an appropriate method to do the same.

the co-ordinates are

```
{
 [10 10]
 [11  1]
 [12  7]
 [14  4]
 [16  8]
 [17  5]]}
```

And `y=0` for all the unmarked x values

[image: The graph plotted with the (x,y) co-ordinates]

Comment: The area between which boundaries?

Comment: The area under each of the peaks in the curve

Comment: Would you be including the area from x=9 and after x=17? Is it safe to assume y=0 for all unmarked x values?

Comment: Yes! y=0 for all the unmarked values

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-integration-new/ab-6-2/a/understanding-the-trapezoid-rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit simple and correct?

```
points = [[10, 10],
          [11, 1],
          [12, 7],
          [14, 4],
          [16, 8],
          [17, 5]]

areas = []
areas.append( points[0][0]/2.0 )

for i in range(0, points[-1][0] - points[0][0]-2):

    if ( points[i+1][0] == points[i][0]+1 ):
        areas.append( (points[i+1][1] + points[i][1] )/2.0)
    elif ( points[i+1][0] >= points[i][0]+2):
        areas.append( (points[i][1] )/2.0)
        areas.append( (points[i+1][1] )/2.0)

areas.append( points[-1][1]/2.0 )    

print(areas)
>[5.0, 5.5, 4.0, 3.5, 2.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.5, 2.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to process one by one for each trapezoid.

```
Area_1 = ( y1 + y2 ) * 1 / 2
```

example : `(10 + 1 ) * 1 / 2`

Comment: This doesn't really answer how you would program it, though. For example, do you loop two points at a time? Not each area is a trapezoid either, some are triangles, so `(y1+y2)` could be 0, but the area is not zero between x=13-15

Comment: Yes, not all area is a perfect trapezoid. Triangle doesn't change the result. if y1+y2 is zero result is zero! There are no points like x =13 or x = 15. I simply gave the method. If he knows the Python rest should be easy, right?

Comment: Look at the graph, though, there's a triangle. Area under that curve should be `1/2 * 2 * 4 = 4`, not zero

Comment: Area for Trapezoid is actually can calculate an area of Triangle. Just keep on side 0 for the formula in the Trapezoid.